# Java exec, SSH login and then using cat command

Tags: java, ssh

I am trying to login to a linux machine using SSH and then add public key to the default authorized_keys file, using Java exec command.

```
String mycommand = "ssh root@1.1.1.1 -i /home/user/login.pem " +"add `cat /home/user/publickey.pub`";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mycommand);
p.waitFor();
```

When I open the authorized_key file I see add `cat /home/user/publickey.pub` instead of the actual contents of the key inserted in the file. Please help me.

Comment: Dont focus on the java part; first make sure that all these commands do what you expect them to do when you simply run them on the command line. And if that already fails, you might better turn to a place like superuser.com or so.

Comment: Yes the command works well when I execute it from command line.

Comment: i have the same issue,
most of the commands work
but cat command isn't executing as it ask for input.